# Слайдер из картинок при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть картинки и описание к ним.

Нужно чтобы при наведении на какой-то текст выплывала картинка и через какое-то время другая, и так со всеми текстами. Как это можно реализовать. У меня есть такой вариант, но тут просто при наведении на текст меняется картинка и то только одна. Есть варианты как можно сделать этот слайдер?

```css
.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/1.png);
  width: 236px;
  height: 420px;
  transition: 1s;
  background-size: cover;
}

p1:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/8.png);
}

p2:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/9.png);
}

p3:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/11.png);
}

p4:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/5.png);
}
```

```html
<p1 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center xs-mb50 xs-font wow fadeIn">
      <p>Text1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</p1>
<p2 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center wow fadeIn">
      <p>Text2</p><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</p2>
<div class="pic" style="border-radius: 20px;"></div>
<p3 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center xs-mb50 xs-font wow fadeIn">
      <p>Text3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</p3>
<p4 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center wow fadeIn">
      <p>Text4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</p4>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Надо создать коллекцию фото. 

let photoCollection = [
  [
    'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/45/eb/d3/45ebd3ed4d9166cc86fb1cfc4a0da63e.jpg',
    'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/a0/b7/de/a0b7de0f8cfef4d42770281cb946ae7c.jpg'
  ],
  [
    'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/68/e8/ee/68e8ee1b4e6275b87e9e283075e4c44a--beautiful-red-dresses-beautiful-ladies.jpg',
    'https://sollys.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/02-1-236x420.jpg'
  ],
  [
    'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/24/94/66/2494660924750e1d345f15ecf5e927a6--selfie-sexy-selfie-stick.jpg',
    'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/24/85/5e/24855ea5091808c98f0c744a16e7195d--margot-robbie-sexy-laura-vandervoort.jpg'
  ],
  [
    'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/90/be/d4/90bed43fb91bf0c56359521569845270.jpg',
    'https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=375x640:format=jpg/path/s3392bf89f9e5511a/image/i4984d86d8a01451e/version/1479749964/image.jpg'
  ]
];
const showElement = document.querySelector('.show-element');
let timer;

// создаем функцию  которая будет запускаться при наведении на объекты span

[...document.querySelectorAll('.hover-element')].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
  s.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    showElement.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + photoCollection[i][0] + ')';
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      showElement.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + photoCollection[i][1] + ')';
    }, 2500)
  })
  s.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    showElement.style.backgroundImage = 'url()';
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2b2b2b;
}

.main-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background: orange;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: fantasy;
}

.show-element {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 236px;
  height: 420px;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url();
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="wrap">
    <span class="hover-element">Text_1</span>
    <span class="hover-element">Text_2</span>
    <span class="hover-element">Text_3</span>
    <span class="hover-element">Text_4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="show-element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: извините, но не работает. при наведении ничего не происходит. И еще вопрос: если у меня картинки на локальном компьютере, то как сделать коллекцию из них? Спасибо.

Comment: @timur, путь к картинке от файла `js`

Comment: а какую ошибку выдает? что в консоли?

Comment: Допустим у тебя две папки на одном уровне... `js && image`, путь будет такой  `../image/fotoname.png`

Comment: в консоли ничего не пишет. Ничего не происходит. У Вас работает?

Comment: как видишь работает

Comment: а в чем тогда проблема может быть?

Comment: и ещё, он у вас как слайдер работает? То есть следующая картинка исчезает или просто передвигается и ее видно?

Comment: @Air прикольные девушки (+), теперь я знаю твои вкусы :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, )))))))